# Despite changes in code my Android app isn't reinstalling onto my AVD in Eclipse?

Tags: android

I keep getting the message 'Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front' despite making changes to the code. I wasn't aware of changing any settings in Eclipse besides creating a new AVD and it was working fine earlier today. Now it's not reinstalling at all.

Comment: are you saving the files? there's a setting that controls whether files are automatically saved before a run.

Comment: Yes, it asks me before each compile when there has been changes whether I want to and despite answering yes it still has this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to start the task manager and end multiple AVD emulator processes that had somehow built up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the problem started when it did but I installed some updates from Eclipse and Android and it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

There are several thing that you can do to solve this problem:

1. You can close your AVD and then start it again.
2. You can manually uninstall your application using AVD interface (Home - Menu button - Manage apps - All tab - Your app - Force stop/Uninstall).

Comment: you can also do it in terminal $ adb uninstall com.package.name

Answer (score 0):

i also constantly have this problem, even when i change the code. what helps for me is simply to start my application in the debug mode; then it starts without that warning. later when i start the application in the non-debugging mode again it normally starts without that warning (at least for a while).